# Ugly looking tabs in Android 2.38

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I have written a simple tab application (for testing of a real one) and, at first, I was very happy with the results. However, I've installed it on a 2.38 galaxy one, and got this ugly result:[image]

on a android 4, or even 2.33 and 2.34 it working fine. Here for some reason, it's looking like this. Here is the Java code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    {
    private TabWidget m_tab_widget;
private TabHost m_tab_host;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    m_tab_host=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
    m_tab_widget=m_tab_host.getTabWidget();
    m_tab_host.setup();

    addTab("tab1", R.id.tab1);
    addTab("tab2", R.id.tab2);
    addTab("tab3", R.id.tab3);
    addTab("tab3", R.id.tab4);
}

private void  addTab(String title,int id)
{
    TabSpec spec=m_tab_host.newTabSpec("tag");
    spec.setContent(id);
    spec.setIndicator(title);
    m_tab_host.addTab(spec);
}

}
```

Now I know that I can paint my own views on the tabs, but beside that option, am I forgetting something? I have installed other applications on that phone, but it seems that they are all using custom tabs. The native clock app looks just fine, and this is what I want my app to look like (tab wise only)

[image]

I don't know if they are using the classic API or not, but if someone have a solution as to what am I doing wrong, I will be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for custom tabs, you can find [many](http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136) [different](http://adanware.blogspot.de/2012/04/android-custom-tab-layouts-just-using.html) [tutorials](http://vimaltuts.com/android-tutorial-for-beginners/android-custom-tab-layout-example) on the web.

Comment: This is a nice tutorial, but it has nothing with the question I have asked